# Get all child component hrefs using a React higher-order component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

My goal is to add a click handler on all anchor elements with an `href` that links to an external domain.

This is my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import LinkWrapper from './LinkWrapper'

function ComponentWithLinks() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="/">internal link</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="http://example.com/external">external link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>
          <a href="http://google.com">another external link</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const wrapped = LinkWrapper(ComponentWithLinks)

export default wrapped;
```

And this is my wrapper:

```
import React from 'react';

function LinkWrapper(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
}

export default LinkWrapper;
```

The children are nested arbitrarily deep.

How do I capture each so that I can attach a click handler to it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this one is messy, we will use [React.Children API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) to traverse all react elements, and [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) to inject properties (onClick in this case).

```
const injectToChildren = (children, addOnClickToAnchors) =>
  React.Children.map(children, addOnClickToAnchors);

const injectToAnchor = child =>
  React.cloneElement(child, { onClick: () => console.log('New Click') });

const addOnClickToAnchors = child => {
  const children = child.props.children;

  // Recursion end condition
  if (!children) return;

  const isAnchor = child.type === 'a';

  return isAnchor
    ? injectToAnchor(child)
    : {
        ...child,
        // Recursion step
        props: { children: injectToChildren(children, addOnClickToAnchors) }
      };
};

function ComponentWithLinks({ children }) {
  // Map every children recursively
  return injectToChildren(children, addOnClickToAnchors)
}

function App() {
  return (
    <ComponentWithLinks>
      // All kinds of children components
    </ComponentWithLinks>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Inject All Tree]